# How to say "the options go from A to B passing through C"?

Tags: grammar

Say I have three options of doing something:

A= buy a bicycle (自転車を買う）

B= buy a High speed car　（高速な車を買う）

C= buy a motorcycle（オートバイを買う）

How can I say: I could consider A to B passing through C. Something like 
"I could consider my options from buying a bicycle to buy  a high speed car including also buying a motorcycle"

so going from one extreme to the other passing through a middle option

Comment: Uh, I’m having trouble understanding the English...

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I think this is the sentence the OP is looking to translate:  "My options (in order of price) go from buying a bicycle, through buying a motorbike (all the way  up to) buying a high speed car".